# trisurf with triangle information and value at centroids

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, `trisurf` renders the triangle surface with value at nodes. If I only know the value at the centroids, how to plot?

Some thoughts:
If n triangles share the same node `N0`, triangle 1 uses 2 other nodes of `N1` and `N2`, triangle 2 uses `N2` and `N3`,...,triangle n uses `Nn` and `N1`, and each triangle centroid is Ci, i=1,...,N, then

```
f(C1)=1/3*(f0+f1+f2)
f(C2)=1/3*(f0+f2+f3)
f(C3)=1/3*(f0+f3+f4)
...
f(Cn)=1/3*(f0+fn+f1)
```

Basically there are n+1 unknowns, I suppose we cannot solve these equations. Any suggestions,if we can make approximations(as small as possible)? Thanks!